# Is it permissible for Muslims to eat with non-Muslims?

Tags: sunni

I want to know, can Muslims eat and sit with non-Muslims?

Because where I am working right now there are non-Muslims working with me and we have accommodation where we are staying together. I never ever felt that eating with non-Muslims is wrong. but now I want to know if this is right or wrong.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please explain what make you even think that it might not allowed to eat with them? I strongly recommend you to take your time to take our 2 min. [tour] and check the [help] to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 2):

In the name of Allah

There's no restriction in eating with a non-Muslim, not from Ahl Alketab (Jews and Christians) nor any other religion. Allah does not forbid us from dealing justly with non-Muslims who do not fight us for religious reasons or depart us from our homes.

The only thing about food and non-Muslims is the food itself, you have to make sure you eat halal food, and this is another question.